# How do I display a table of boolean values from a file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to display a table of boolean values from a file and not sure how to create one or where to start. I run the inputted values through my logic gate and display the results. This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool andGate(bool a, bool b) { return a & b; }
bool notGate(bool z) { return ~ z; }
bool orGate(bool xy, bool yz) { return xy | yz; }
void display(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool f) { cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << ' ' << setw(3) << f << endl; }

int main() {
    bool x, y, z, f;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  // Gets each row
        cout << "Input (x, y, z): ";
        cin >> x >> y >> z >> f;
    }

    // needs to be in table format
    cout << "X Y Z F(x,y,z)" << endl;
    display(x, y, z, orGate(andGate(x, y), andGate(y, notGate(z)))); // display the row

    return 0;
}
```

For example, I run this file that contains these numbers: (x, y, z, f)

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
```

How would I display them in a table view like this?

```
x    y    z    F(x,y,z)
0    0    0       1
0    0    1       1
0    1    0       0
0    1    1       0
1    0    0       0
1    0    1       0
1    1    0       0
1    1    1       0
```

Comment: Your input has a fourth column but you are trying to display the result of a function instead of the fourth entry per row?

Comment: That's how my professor does it. The fourth column is ignored in the code. Not sure why he does it like that.

Comment: Use `&&`, `!`, and `||` for boolean values. The operators that you're using are for bitwise operations on integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool andGate(bool a, bool b) { return a & b; }
bool notGate(bool z) { return ~z; } 
bool orGate(bool xy, bool yz) { return xy | yz; }
void display(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool f) { cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z 
<< ' ' << "|" <<setw(3) << f << endl; }

int main(){
bool x, y, z, f;

cout << "X Y Z F(x,y,z)" << endl<<endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  // Gets each row
    fin >> x >> y >> z >> f;

    display(x, y, z, orGate(andGate(x, y), andGate(y, notGate(z)))); // display the row
    cout << "\n----------\n";
}
 return 0;
}
```

for spacing you might use extra tabs...

I think so , this might be your desired output.

Comment: The way I would input the file is with this command ' ./truthtable < table1.txt ' and not with the ifstream. The ifstream would work if I would do 1 file, but I'm testing multiple files.

Comment: Always check if command line arguments exist before using them. Also, you forgot to change your main signature, which needs the return type (`int`) and the command line arguments.

Comment: ./truthtable  <truth.txt > save.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt the user with `"Input (x, y, z): "` for each row and not display each row at the same time then you will have to store the input in a data structure which will be displayed after user input is done:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool andGate(bool a, bool b) { return a & b; }
bool notGate(bool z) { return ~z; }
bool orGate(bool xy, bool yz) { return xy | yz; }

int main() {
    // A data structure to store the input
    std::vector<std::array<bool, 3>> table;

    // Store the input in the data structure
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        bool x, y, z, junk;
        std::cout << "Input (x, y, z): ";
        std::cin >> x >> y >> z >> junk;
        table.push_back({ x, y, z });
    }

    // Display the data structure. It is easy enough to just put the exact
    // spacing manually
    std::cout << "x    y    z    F(x,y,z)\n";
    for (const auto& row : table) {
        const bool F = orGate(andGate(row[0], row[1]), andGate(row[1], notGate(row[2])));
        std::cout << row[0] << "    "
                  << row[1] << "    "
                  << row[2] << "       "
                  << F << "\n";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

On a side note, the combinations of function in `F` does not match the output you showed in your question. Maybe you intended to use `&&`, `!`, and `||` instead of `&`, `~`, and `|` (however doing that still does not match the output in the question)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is read `stdin` and output your truth table until you run out of data, then all you need to read from `stdin` is `cin`, e.g.:

```
    while (cin >> x >> y >> z >> f)
        display(x, y, z, orGate(andGate(x, y), andGate(y, notGate(z))));
```

To format your output exactly as you have shown, you just need to tweak your output format slightly, e.g.

```
void display(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool f)
{
    cout << x << "    " << y << "    " << z << "    " 
        << setw(4) << f << endl;
}
```

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool andGate(bool a, bool b) { return a & b; }
bool notGate(bool z) { return ~ z; }
bool orGate(bool xy, bool yz) { return xy | yz; }

void display(bool x, bool y, bool z, bool f)
{
    cout << x << "    " << y << "    " << z << "    " 
        << setw(4) << f << endl;
}

int main (void) {

    bool x, y, z, f;

    cout << "X    Y    Z    F(x,y,z)" << endl;
    while (cin >> x >> y >> z >> f)
        display(x, y, z, orGate(andGate(x, y), andGate(y, notGate(z))));

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/truthtable <dat/table1.txt
X    Y    Z    F(x,y,z)
0    0    0       0
0    0    1       0
0    1    0       1
0    1    1       1
1    0    0       0
1    0    1       0
1    1    0       1
1    1    1       1
```

If your question is different, let me know with a comment.